# To get a part of the text file using matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have  text file which starts with the following

```
*******************************************
*                                         *
* DRILL LIST REPORT                       *
*                                         *
* H:\DATALOGGER\CIRCUIT\DATALOGGER-2.MAX  *
* Fri Sep 30 14:54:00 2011                *
*                                         *
*******************************************

COMMENTS   DRILL    TOOL     XCOORD       YCOORD       
-------------------------------------------------------
THRUHOLES
            0.10 cm 1         -17.51 cm    16.28 cm
```

I want to retrieve just the XCOORD and YCOORD from the file.
there are about 300 lines in this file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `headerlines` flag, of `textread`, or `textscan`.
See documentation for more information.